# How to use .on_delete callback in ProMotion-Formotion

Tags: rubymotion

I use ProMotion with PM::FormotionScreen screen.

How to use row[.on_delete callback](https://github.com/clayallsopp/formotion#callbacks) from Formotion in ProMotion?

I have this table_data method

```
  def table_data
    {
      sections: [{
          rows: [

          {
          title: "URL",
          key: :url,
          placeholder: "http://myapp/dj_mon/",
          action: :delete_account,
          deletable: true,
          type: :string,
          auto_correction: :no,
          auto_capitalization: :none
          }

          ]
        }]
    }
  end
```

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1dlu.png

Comment: I'm not enough of a Formotion expert to know how to select the cell so you can do the callback. This is definitely a Formotion thing, not a ProMotion thing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a hash to initialize the Formotion form, you'll have to use the DSL:

```
form = Formotion::Form.new

form.build_section do |section|
  section.build_row do |row|
    row.title               = 'URL'
    row.key                 = :url
    row.placeholder         = "http://myapp/dj_mon/"
    row.type                = :string
    row.auto_correction     = :no
    row.auto_capitalization = :none
    row.deletable           = true

    row.on_tap do |row|
      p "I'm tapped!"
    end

    row.on_delete do |row|
     p "I'm called before the delete animation"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I know this is old, but this should be accepted as the correct answer - it solved my [slightly different] query. Thanks @Devon!